# mongoose + typescript schema/interface (problem with $push and Array of object interface)

Tags: arrays, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, interface

so basically i have 2 problems:

first is im getting this error:

```
Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
```

on all the items inside the schema. this actually does not prevent from the schema to work however it might be part of the bigger problem and anyways its a problem i would like to get rid off.

the bigger problem is that im getting these errors:

```
error TS2322: Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.
error TS2322: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.
error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

which wont let me compile without using  @ts-expect-error above the function that cause the problem.

this is the function that trigger the problem:

```
        await AutoUsersPositions.updateOne(
            { user: userSetup.userEmail },
            { $push: { stocks: { id: position._id, active: true, createdAt: Date.now() } } }
        )
```

the problem is being triggered by the keys "id" ,"active" and "createdAt".

this is the full schema and interface:

```
import {Document, model, Schema, Types } from "mongoose";

export interface optionsArray extends Document{
    id: any, 
    active: Boolean, 
    createdAt: Number
}


export interface AutoUsersPositionsDocument extends Document {
    user?: string,
    userID?: string,
    stocks?: [optionsArray],
    bonds?: [optionsArray],
    comodity?: [optionsArray],
    currencyPairs?: [optionsArray],
    indexes?: [optionsArray],
    [key: string]: any

}

const AutoUsersPositionSchema = new Schema({ //סכמה משתמש
    user: String, 
    userID: String,
    stocks:  [Schema.Types.Mixed],
    bonds: [Schema.Types.Mixed],
    comodity: [Schema.Types.Mixed],
    currencyPairs: [Schema.Types.Mixed],
    indexes: [Schema.Types.Mixed],
}, { collection: "AutoUsersPositions"} );

const AutoUsersPositions = model<AutoUsersPositionsDocument>("AutoUsersPositions", AutoUsersPositionSchema);
export default AutoUsersPositions;
```

any idea what can cause the problem? by the way the 2nd problem started happening after adding the index signature: `[key:string]: any` but i need this index signature for dynamic option